# Get Address Book contact's group?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the group(s) a particular contact belongs to?

Let's say I got the array of all contacts:

```
NSMutableArray *people = [[[(NSArray*) 
      ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook) autorelease] 
      mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

and then iterate through them:

```
for (int personN = 0; personN < [people count]; personN++) {
ABRecordRef person = [people objectAtIndex:personN];
NSString* firstName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, 
                      kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
//and so on...
}
```

How can I get the group name(s) for the person? On MacOS there's ABPerson class that has parentGroups method that does what I need, but I don't see anything like that on iOS.

I suppose it is possible to instead get the array of all groups, then iterate though that groups array and retrieve the contact records for each group, but I was hoping there was a more direct way for that?

P.S. Looks like there is no way to do that but to iterate through groups. One caveat for those who'd find this question later: to get all contacts, you have to iterate through groups and get members of each group (ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers), then iterate through all contacts (ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople) because there's no "null" group. Also note that ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople will also give you the contacts you already fetched with ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers calls, so be sure to check for duplicates.

Comment: I think there is no direct way :( you can iterate group array only

Comment: @Sergnsk yes, looks like iterating through groups array it is.

Comment: If you found a solution to this question, you'd better answer it yourself and accept the answer. This will help incoming readers a lot. Otherwise, starting a bounty will be a great way to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out http://ericasadun.com for ABRecordHelper

there is a method to return the group name from a recordID. very helpful wrapper.

Comment: Seems like a useful collection of Address Book wrappers, so - accepting the answer.